# need assistance with writing random array values to a file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

I am struggling with a beginning Java class.  I have to modify a program to replace a user-generated integer array with a `Random()` number generated double precision floating point array.

This is what I have so far.  I think it is generating the correct dataset, but I can't get the `PrintWriter` section configured correctly.

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assign6array;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author matthew.neesley
 */
public class Assign6Array {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int count = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        Random rd = new Random(); // creating Random object
        double[] arr = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = rd.nextInt(); // storing random integers in an array
            while (numbers!= -1 && count <= 9)
            {
                array[count] = numbers;
                count++;
                System.out.println(arr[i]); // printing each array element
                PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(System.out);
                printr.print(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be making it a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Do you simply have to generate ten random `double`s and print them? I copied and ran the code in your question (after fixing the compilation error) and it simply printed the exact same number several times. Do you think that is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `PrintWriter` like this

```
PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(System.out);
```

The variable is named `writer`, but you use it like this:

```
printr.print(arr[i]);
```

Using `printr` variable which doesn't exist. Do simply:

```
writer.print(arr[i]);
```

Also, you need `PrintStream` acts as a buffer, so you will have to flush it's contents so that they are written to the output stream.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * @author matthew.neesley
 */
public class Assign6Array {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] array = new int[10];
    int count = 0;
    int numbers = 0;

    Random rd = new Random(); // creating Random object
    double[] arr = new double[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = rd.nextInt(); // storing random integers in an array

      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
      while (numbers != -1 && count <= 9) {
        array[count] = numbers;
        count++;
        System.out.println("abc " + arr[i]); // printing each array element
        writer.println(arr[i]);
        writer.flush();
      }
      writer.close();
    }
  }
}
```